# System.out.println not working (Console is Visible)

Tags: java, println, system.out

Ok so i'm new to Java and I've just tried to run a simple bit of code (in Eclipse) that looks for a class and prints out either working or not working depending on if it finds said class.

Furthermore I put a println right in the main function as well. The full code is:

```
package jampez.location;

public class MySQLConn {
    public static void connection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jbdc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Worked");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Not Worked");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Trying");
        connection();
    }
}
```

Basically the issue is that it is just not displaying the println's and even after googling I still can't seem to get it working.
Below is the return I get from running the code. I would expect to see Trying followed by either Working or Not Working.

[image]

Comment: Where do you expect it to printout? Also, you have a typo in the mysql jdbc driver type name.

Comment: Are you definitely running it?

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: What's the exact output?

Comment: Did you save your code before running it?

Comment: I'm expecting it in console. The console does show the terminated string which according to google means it is being run.  And yes I did save it

Comment: @jampez77 Please show the exact command you use to run your program. Also, what does "terminated string" mean? Show us the actual output you see.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Im going to edit the question to show what I mean by the terminated string. And i'm not using a command within the code, i just click run at the top of eclipse

Comment: What is in the LogCat tab?

Comment: Nothing in the LogCat tab

Comment: Clean and rebuild your code. Check your run configurations. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Cleaned, rebuilt and still the same issue. even if i strip back the code to just a hello world message with nothing more I still get nothing even after restarting eclipse

Comment: You are sure you running this code?  Maybe you are running another program?

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes. How would I make sure?

Comment: The error you reported below trying to debug, `Cannot connect to VM Socket closed`, strongly suggests you are *NOT* running the code.  Q: Is the application an Android app?  A web app?  Or just a normal "Java application"?

Comment: The project is an Android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your project is an Android App (as you stated in the comments), you can't have a main method and run it. The main method equivalent for Android Apps would be `onCreate()`, but I think that's not what you want.

To get your code working you have two options:

1. Put your class`MySQLConn` in a new default Java project and run it.
2. Create a new default Java project with a main method and call your class from there.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is vague and without info enough, I'll give you a complete answer about sending info to the console:

Whenever you start a program in a console by using a command line, this console will be considered your main output device. All languages support sending information to the output device. In the case of java this is done with the methods from System class. Calling System.out.print in any of its variations will definitelly send the parameters of the function call to your terminal. So if you have executed your program as:

```
> javac MyProgram.java
> java MyProgram
```

You'll get the output in that console.

If you are using an IDE to compile, build and run your program, your IDE is managing the output calls, as there are no console. This doesn't mean there's no output device, but that the IDE is a pipe between the execution and the terminal. You'll have to find a way to display the results from the console. Probably you'll have to look for a menu in a View menu.

By the way, your code doesn't even compile, so instead of looking to the console tab of your IDE (probably empty), look in the Build or Solution tab. You should find the compilation errors there.

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Fix these two typos:

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

`public static void main(String[] args)`

2) Make sure the code actually compiles (for example, Windows > Views > Problems, then look at the "Problems" tab")

3) "Debug As"; make sure "Stop in main" is ENABLED

Comment: Fixed typos, no problems in problem tabs, enabled stop in main and still nothing im afraid

Comment: So "Debug As", and single-step through (F5 or F6).  Q: Does the debugger actually *enter* your main()?  Does it execute the first System.out.println() (can you step past it in the debugger)?  Or does it terminate immediately.  Do you see any warnings?  Any execeptions?

Comment: If I try to debug I get the following error....Cannot connect to VM
Socket closed

Comment: How many entries are listed under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`?

Comment: GOOD INFORMATION - Thank you: `Cannot connect to VM Socket closed`.  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752064/eclipse-when-launching-in-debug-mode-show-cannot-connect-to-vm-error.  Q: What kind of "java application" are you building?  Android? A web service?  Or just a "standard java app"?

Comment: it is an Android app

Comment: @Leistungsabfall There is one entry under Installed JREs

Comment: @jampez77 JRE or JDK?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall 1.6.0.jdk